# probability: When $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, the med = $\mu$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, error-function

> The median of a PDF is defined as the point $x = $med for which $P[X\leq\text{med}] = 1/2$. Prove that if $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, then med $= \mu$.

---

Since $P[X\leq\text{med}] = 1/2$, we need to determine
  $$                                                                           
  \Phi(x) - \Phi(-\infty) = 1 - Q(x) - 1 - Q(-\infty) = 1 - Q(x) = \frac{1}{2}  
  $$
  Thus, the we need the value of $x$ such that $Q(x) = 1/2$.
  \begin{gather*}
    Q(x) =
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\frac{x - \mu}{\sigma}}^{\infty}e^{-t^2/2}dt\\
    \frac{1}{2}\text{erfc}\Big[\frac{x - \mu}{\sigma\sqrt{2}}\Big]
    = \frac{1}{2}\\
    \text{erfc}\Big[\frac{x - \mu}{\sigma\sqrt{2}}\Big] = 1
  \end{gather*}
I know that $\text{erfc}(0) = 1$ but is there a more succinct way to prove $x = \mu$ without saying from prior knowledge we know that $\text{erfc}(0) = 1$ so $x$ must be $\mu$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below theorem will make our proof very easy.

> If $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then pdf is symmetric about $\mu$

Proof: Note that proving symmetry about $\mu$ boils down to proving that for $\epsilon>0$ that $f(\mu+\epsilon)=f(\mu-\epsilon)$. thus we see that 
$$f(\mu-\epsilon)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{\frac{\left((\mu-\epsilon)-\mu\right)^2}{\sigma^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{\frac{\left(-\epsilon\right)^2}{\sigma^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{\frac{\left(\epsilon\right)^2}{\sigma^2}}$$
and 
$$f(\mu+\epsilon)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{\frac{\left((\mu+\epsilon)-\mu\right)^2}{\sigma^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{\frac{\left(\epsilon\right)^2}{\sigma^2}}$$
thus $f(\mu+\epsilon)=f(\mu-\epsilon)$.

With this theorem we now see that 
$$P(X>\mu)=\int_\mu^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{\frac{\left(x-\mu\right)^2}{\sigma^2}}dx=P(X<\mu)$$
And since $P(X>\mu)+P(X<\mu)=1$ we have $2P(X>\mu)=1$ thus $P(X>\mu)=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: This was going off of what Simon S. was saying just wanted to say it really explicitly cause in comments it seems like you might have still been confused

Answer (score 3):

The normal pdf is symmetric about the mean, isn't that enough?

Comment: Not for me.  I have the proof above pretty much complete so that is what I am building off.

Comment: "Not for me" Why?

Comment: @Did because I am not assuming that is known and it wasn't giving.  Therefore, I am proving it from the information giving which leads to my last line $$\text{erfc}\Big[\frac{x-\mu}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\Big] = 1$$

Comment: @dustin just look at the equation for the pdf and show that $f(-x)=f(x)$ QED its not that you are not assuming it, you are actually ignoring very relevant information.

Comment: Fully agree with @Eupraxis1981's comment.